# Menus come down on browser resize

Tags: html, css

I have been facing problem for my horizontal menu bar code.

This menu bar displays correctly for 1366 x 768 resolution

but after pressing ctrl - short key

when I reduce browser size using ctrl - short key my menus come down. I have tried both em and px units to be used for this problem but it does not seem to solve the problem. I want to clarify that menu bar must be in center as the other things in whole page and should be expanded for the whole 960px setting for wrapper. I need help for sorting out this problem.

Below is my source code

### HTML

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav_wrapper">
    <div class="menu_box">
      <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='index.php' class="active"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>About Us</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Courses</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='index.php'>AGP Program</a></li>
              <li><a href='index.php'>Web Program</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Partners</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Consultancy</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>News n Events</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

### CSS

```
/* MEDIA QUERIES FOR A RESPONSIVE LAYOUT */

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:0.4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: #565656;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #565656), color-stop(100%, #323232));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    max-height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
  #cssmenu.expand ul {
    max-height: 900px;
  }
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  background: #444444;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444444 0%, #323232 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #444444), color-stop(100%, #323232));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444444 0%, #323232 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#444444 0%, #323232 100%);
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.mobile i {
    float: right;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  border-right: 0px solid #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 4px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
  border-right: 0 none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 2.61em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
}
/* Sub menu */
#cssmenu ul ul {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #000000 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 5px 12px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: 0;
  width: 110px;
  z-index: 1;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu ul ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 92%;
  }
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

/*  Menus  */       
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) 
{   
.middle_section{
        width:100%;
        background-color:#D6D6D6;
/*      background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #C40302 0%, #9E0302 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); */
}

nav{
    background: linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}

.nav_wrapper{
    background: linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
}
```

---

Comment: I would recommend testing browsing resizing with actually resizing the browser, and not zooming in and out (`ctrl +/-`). Also what do you mean with "my menus come down"?

Comment: Use min-width for #cssmenu, so it will not get squeezed after a specific width.

Comment: As I correctly understand you need justifying text to the whole width of wrapper? Am I right?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. @MeRuud i wanted to say menus of my design.

Comment: @Taimur when I used min-width with #cssmenu menus become left aligned which is not satisfactory for my clients.

Comment: @AlexPrinceton I need horizontal menu bar to be expanded fully in 960px nav_wrapper and when I resize it using ctrl - short key none of the menus should come down.

Answer (score 0):

This might be simply solved by adding `min-width` to on of the wraping elements, in this case I finde it to work better when applied to "nav_wrapper". Also, when working with an element bigger than the display, it's good to have no margin in the body element, so I changed that too.

Here's the changes I made

**CSS**

```
body{
        margin: 0px;
    }
.nav_wrapper{
        min-width: 980px;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HzpEE/)